# How to control the screen rotation in ubuntu 12.10 via an icon on the panel?

Tags: 12.10, screen, monitor, rotate-monitor

Is there is a program that displays an icon in the panel, to control the rotation of the monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a launcher using Unity quicklists (right click menus) to provide you with rotation options:

The result will be something like this:

[image: img]

You just need to follow these steps:

1. Create a new text file with this content:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Rotate Screen
   Exec=notify-send 'Choose an option from the quicklist' -t 2000 -i rotate
   Terminal=false
   X-MultipleArgs=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=rotate
   StartupNotify=false
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Normal;Inverted;Right;Left

   [Right Shortcut Group]
   Name=Rotate Right
   Exec=xrandr -o right
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Left Shortcut Group]
   Name=Rotate Left
   Exec=xrandr -o left
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Normal Shortcut Group]
   Name=Normal
   Exec=xrandr -o normal
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Inverted Shortcut Group]
   Name=Invert 
   Exec=xrandr -o inverted
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
2. Save the file with a `.desktop` extension.
3. Make the new file executable (it will be called "Rotate Screen") through
   Right click → Properties → Permissions tab → Allow executing files as program
4. Click and drag the file onto the launcher.

Answer (score 2):

create a shortcut to for example: `xrandr -o right`

Comment: Could you explain how to create the shortcut and how to put it on the  panel?

Comment: @EricCarvalho http://askubuntu.com/a/95825/182500

Answer (score -1):

As for creating a desktop shortcut to rotate your screen, I think [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193947) might be helpful.

Edited:
This will help you to create a desktop executable file to rotate your screen either to left, right, 180 degree, back to normal.(multiple files)
**For Rotate Left:** 
1- In Terminal:

```
xrandr
```

look at the output and see what is connected (LVDS1, HDMI, VGA1, DP1,.. ). I will consider here that **LVDS1** is connected.
2- 
`cd ~/Desktop` 
`gedit rotate_left.desktop` 
3- paste the following code inside the opened text editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=rotate_left
Exec=xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate left
Name[en_US]=rotate_left
```

save and close.
4- In Terminal:

```
sudo chmod 755 rotate_Left.desktop
```

Now you have an executable file on your desktop to rotate screen left. 
To rotate differently, just replace the word "left" with "right" inverted", "normal". 
Hope this was helpful :-)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please provide a summary of this solution?

Comment: I am new here, so thanks for the comments. Editing is done.