# change screen orientation shortcut?

Tags: 13.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

In windows I can change screen orientation by "Ctrl + Alt + Arrow" as Arrow can be up, left, down or right.

What is the shortcut on Ubuntu? thanks!

Comment: Use `xrandr -o right` to turn it right and `xrandr -o normal` to put the screen back in the normal direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a default keyboard shortcut for this, but you could easily define one yourself. The commands for rotating the screen are:

```
xrandr --rotate left
xrandr --rotate normal
xrandr --rotate right
```

You should be able to define your own shortcuts in the "Keyboard" application (Shortcuts tab), as explained here: [How can I rotate my display in the most easy way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95812/how-can-i-rotate-my-display-in-the-most-easy-way). If this works for you, that's great! However, I wasn't able to make it work this way.

As an alternative, you may want to delete the functions that are assigned to the keyboard combinations originally (they should be in the "Windows" section of the previous tab). After that, install a small program called "xbindkeys" to assign these keys.

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Create a configuration file:

```
gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

and enter this inside the config file

```
"xrandr --rotate left"
Control+Alt + Left
"xrandr --rotate right"
Control+Alt + Right
"xrandr --rotate normal"
Control+Alt + Up
```

Hope this works out for you. You can find more info on xbindkeys online!

Answer (score 15):

@Dionos's answer is good. On 13.10, I found that the correct commands to rotate are:

```
xrandr -o left
xrandr -o right
xrandr -o normal
xrandr -o inverted
```

Moreover you can use builtin settings for custom shortcuts. [Windows] > type: "keyboard" > select keyboard settings ("Keyboard") > [Shortcuts] > "Custom shortcuts" > [+]. After adding you can assign a shortcut.

Comment: Tried for "xrandr program version 1.3.5; Server reports RandR version 1.4" on Ubuntu 12.04. Only `xrandr -o normal|left|right` works.

Comment: @chris thanks for the post. it's working fine