# How to create a keyboard shortcut to rotate the monitor in Unity?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, rotate-monitor

I am new to linux and I tried to set up a keyboard shortcut that would rotate my second screen, however, when I use the command nothing happens. Is there something else I have to configure to ensure my custom keyboard shortcuts work? The built in commands work, just not the custom ones I created. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the directions I found on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95812/how-can-i-rotate-my-display-in-the-most-easy-way) and wrote the following in the command line.

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate left
```

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> as the shortcut.

When I type that command in the terminal, everything works great. Just not with the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, install compizconfig-settings-manager. Then open it up by calling

```
ccsm
```

Then, there is a keyboard shortcut plugin. You need to enable this plugin and set the plugin here.

Unity itself is a compiz plugin so when the settings in Unity don't work, they usually do in compiz as that is the main engine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up System Settings.
2. In the window, navigate to Keyboard settings in the Hardware section.
3. Navigate to Shortcuts tab.
4. Select the Custom Shortcuts from the list in the left side pane.
5. You would see a <kbd>+</kbd> button in the bottom right pane. Click that button.
6. In the another opened window, just specify any name for the shortcut and specify the command that you would want to execute once the shortcut key pressed and then click Apply button.
7. Once the shortcut is created in the right side pane, you would have to assign the shortcut key by just clicking the Disabled text of the selected shortcut in the list. Assign the shortcut key you would like to. Now, you are ready to use the shortcut key.